# Is it safe to deploy a Google Webmaster Tools verification file to multiple environments?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

A client wants to use webmaster tools on his site so we have to add a verification file to the site root. 
We have a continuous build with TeamCity setup for this site so to make sure that the file will be there I added the file to the deployment package. Because we have DTAP environments setup this means it will be deployed to multiple environments.

Is it safe or wise to deploy the file to multiple environments or should I wright some logic in the configuration to exclude the file from deployment to the other environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verification for all the sites will be connected to the Google account that created/downloaded that verification file (i.e. you will not be able to remove that account from the webmaster tools/search console account without re-verifying). Frankly I only realized this when I changed jobs and had to hand over my Google Account since verification was tied to that account (bit of a bugger since this lost me all Google certifications connected with that account).

Other than that there is no problem - you will be able to create a WMT account for every page that has the file uploaded (the verification file is created once per Google account, not per monitored site), so if that's what you want you should be okay.

If there is a properly set up (i.e. code deployed as per Google documentation) Analytics or Tag Manager account in the page verification can be done by a GA/GTM administrator without the need for a verification file.

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to deploy this file on your **production** environment.

But also you can deploy this file to **development**, **test** and **acceptance** environment. For example, you can add some testing for availability of this file, conflicts with url routing etc. If your development, test and acceptance setup done right there is no risks to safety. So make sure environments other than production done right: maybe robots.txt, noindex tags, may be basic authorization.